# How do I infuse the crystalline shard?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

Before leaving the Changing God's resonance chamber you find a Crystalline Shard which you can use as a light weapon. From various wiki sites I know that it

> can be upgraded to an Infused Crystalline Shard by extending it to the obelisk in the Reef of Fallen Worlds.

How exactly do you perform the operation since the dialog options do not seem to show it to me?

Comment: Did you equip the shard as your weapon? I did and the option to extend it to the obelisk was there.

Comment: @Dulkan Yes, it was equipped as a weapon as soon as I got it. I have a very bad feeling that I might have encountered a glitch where the option never appeared, or it was a one shot option that doesn't reappear.

Comment: Might be possible. You could try starting a new game to see whether it shows up there. Otherwise I wouldn't sweat it. It's not a very good weapon anyway and you don't need the infused shard for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [this](http://torment.wikia.com/wiki/Infused_Crystalline_Shard) wiki.

It states that you must stretch the standard crstalline shard in the reef of fallen worlds:

The regular Crystalline Shard found in the Broken Dome can be upgraded to this infused version by stretching it out in front of the obelisk in the Reef of Fallen Worlds.

The stats and additional information can found on the wiki i linked.

Comment: -1 I mentioned that I know about extending the shard out in the question. The problem is that the option to stretch the shard out does not appear.

Comment: Sorry there. Didn't read the final part. Will do some research :P

Comment: No worries, although I am worried that the reason I didn't get the option might be due to a game glitch.

Comment: Probably. I've seen a few threads and they either didn't have a fix, or they hadn't completed something to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try touching the obelisk? For me the order of events was as follows:

- investigate the obelisk
- select option -> try to touch it (you do not really touch it the first time, no risk of death here)
- Aligern advises against that action
- select option -> use the shard to touch it

Only after Aligerns warning did that option appear (as only at that point do we know what the obelisk does).

Comment: Neither Aligerns or Callistege were in my party since I dismissed them both out of the gate. I wonder if that might have had something to do with the option not appearing.

Comment: @rjzii I didn't try it, but I would guess that in that case you have to touch it and pass the quick fingers test to survive - than your character would know it shoots lazers and should be able to come up with crystal infusion idea.

Comment: I can safely say that passing the quick fingers test with the character by themselves does not lead to the crystal infusion - unless there is a bug in the game - since that is what lead to me asking the question originally.

Comment: @rjzii - Part of Aligern's warning is that the guy who got his face melted doing this had a glass necklace that then glowed like a nightlight.  I would guess making that connection (face + laser = bad, glass + laser = something good?) is what allows you to infuse your shard.  I am not aware of any other way to get that information at this point.